# Understanding ruby on rails validations documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently creating a rails application. 
I am writing a model and wants to add some validation. 
from the documentation I see that doing something like this works

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: { message: 'must be abided' }
end
```

I am trying to understand the validates method here. 
At a more general level I would like to understand rails documentation better. 
My understanding is that validates is a class method of ApplicationRecord::Base.
It is possible to reuse it with various parameters and options.
The best doc I found is [this](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates). 
I do not understand where I can find a list of all validates options and parameters. 
In this case,

- what is acceptance?
- where can I find a description of it in the doc?
- where can I find a list of all other possible validates parameters?

Any tips on how to understand ruby on rails documentation better would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: true
```

`acceptance` maps to `AcceptanceValidator` which is a default rails validator:

*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/acceptance.rb*

All of the default validators are listed in the example:

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates*

```
absence
acceptance
confirmation
exclusion
format
inclusion
length
numericality
presence
```

and additional validators that are added by `ActiveRecord`:

```
associated
uniqueness
```

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html*

Available options for each validaror are documented in the helper methods here:

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html*

```
validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: true
# is the same as using a helper method
validates_acceptance_of :terms_of_service
# and both map to rails default `AcceptanceValidator`
```

You can have custom validators as well:

```
validates :terms_of_service, terms: true # maps to `TermsValidator`

# because there is no TermsValidator class in rails, you have to define it
# class TermsValidator
# # TODO: see docs for examples of custom validators
# end
```

*https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations*